# jQuery tmpl clear

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Does anyone know how to clear a jQuery `tmpl()` so I can re-populate it?  I cant use empty() because i need the rest of the content in the parent. I can use remove, but I need to know how many... wait, i might have just figured it out :)

The template looks like this

```
<table id="lvList" class="grid1">
    <tr id="itemtemplatePlaceHolder">
        <th>Reference</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Postcode</th>
        <th>Tel</th>
        <th>Fax</th>
        <th style="width:50px;">Billing</th>
        <th style="width:50px;">Shipping</th>
    </tr>
    <script id="itemtemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <tr>
            <td><a id="${id}" href="address.aspx?id=${id}" oncontextmenu="ContextMenu.Show(this,event); return false;">${reference}</a></td>
            <td>${$item.nobreak("address", ", ")}</td>
            <td>${country}</td>
            <td>${postcode}</td>
            <td>${tel}</td>
            <td>${fax}</td>
            <td>${$item.bool("defaultbilling", "X", "")}</td>
            <td>${$item.bool("defaultshipping", "X", "")}</td>
        </tr>
    </script>
    <tr id="footertemplate">
        <td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should self-answer your own question. After a day, you will also be able to accept your own answer.

Comment: I need 8 more points before i can self answer :(

Comment: i can now self answer whoop whoop and will edit this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own query :) but just in case anyone else has the same problem, he's what i did

Kept a track of how many items there were in the data list `this.itemcount = data.Count();`, then removed all siblings past the placeholder with an index less than the item count `$("#itemtemplatePlaceHolder ~ :lt(" + this.itemcount + ")").remove()`

```
this.Populate = function () {
    try {
        if (this.itemcount > 0) {
            $("#itemtemplatePlaceHolder ~ :lt(" + this.itemcount + ")").remove();
        }

        var data = this.GetData();
        this.itemcount = data.Count();

        $("#itemtemplate").tmpl(data).insertAfter("#itemtemplatePlaceHolder");
    }
    catch (ex) { this.HandleError(ex); }
};
```